# Make a list consistent

Tags: python

I have 2 list ..

```
a = [{'Work': 'R'}, {'Area': 'S0'}, {'Type': 'PIV'}, {'Disc': 'LA'}, {'L': 'A'}] 
b = [{'Key': '9', 'FileName': '123A.pdf', 'Code': '1', 'Type': 'PNHRG'}]

output -- [{'Key': '9', 'FileName': '123A.pdf', 'Code': '1', 'Type': 'PNHRG','Work': 'R','Area': 'S0','Type': 'PIV','Disc': 'LA','L': 'A'}]
```

I tried 'extend','append','insert' but did not get desired
output. tried all most all list operations with loops too. I am
not in position to change any kind of types for this.

Tried this solution too without luck. not sure where I am missing.

[How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: What is the problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure, that you want a `list` with just one `dict` in it?

Comment: Yes, Jacob.. I want list with one dict in it.

Comment: So basically you have N lists, each with M dictionaries (with distinct keys?) and want to combine all those into a single dict? Why is that still wrapped in a list?

Comment: I am getting this from other sources ( different)  and want to wrapped into a list.

Comment: It is hard to believe that you have tried all list operations if you do not provide any code that works but the output differs from the expected output.

Comment: @RRP there is 0 benefit to having a dict wrapped into a single element list.

Comment: @matszwecja There is sort of a benefit if that's the format you have to use for reasons you can't influence (but otherwise I agree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra from the answer provided by tobias_k:

If you want to combine both lists of dictionaries (and more when you have it) as a dictionary with a list of values in the same key. You can do this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)

for i in (a+b):
    for key, value in i.items():
        mydict[key].append(value)
        

mydict
Out[32]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'Work': ['R'],
             'Area': ['S0'],
             'Type': ['PIV', 'PNHRG'],
             'Disc': ['LA'],
             'L': ['A'],
             'Key': ['9'],
             'FileName': ['123A.pdf'],
             'Code': ['1']})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a doubly-nested dictionary comprehension, iterating over all the items in all the dicts in all the lists. Assuming multiple dicts in `b` might not be necessary, but makes it easier.

```
>>> a = [{'Work': 'R'}, {'Area': 'S0'}, {'Type': 'PIV'}, {'Disc': 'LA'}, {'L': 'A'}] 
>>> b = [{'Key': '9', 'FileName': '123A.pdf', 'Code': '1', 'Type': 'PNHRG'}]
>>> [{k: v for lst in (a, b) for d in lst for k, v in d.items()}]
[{'Work': 'R', 'Area': 'S0', 'Type': 'PNHRG', 'Disc': 'LA', 'L': 'A', 'Key': '9', 'FileName': '123A.pdf', 'Code': '1'}]
```

Addendum: If there are any keys that appear in more than one dictionary, as is the case with `"type"` here, the value from the *last* dictionary that was iterated in the comprehension will be used, i.e. `b` here. If you need the value from `a`, do `... for lst in (b, a)...`. In your expected output, that key appears twice, but that is not possible unless you change the format, as in the other answer.